# Recursion How to find minimum value of a array

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

```
`/* finding the minimum number of a array */
#include<stdio.h>

int minimum(int n, int a[n], int x);

int main(void)
{

  int a[5] = { 5, 4, 3, 4, 5 };
  printf("%d \n", minimum(4, a, 0));
  return 0;
}

int minimum(int n, int a[n], int x)
{
  int minima;
  if (x >= n)
    return a[x];
  else
    minima = minimum(n, a, x + 1);
  if (a[x] > minima)
    return minima;
}
`
```

Hey I read few recursion sources in stackoverflaw. Also found same kind problem using JAVA. Can you please explain me how this code works.Or is this a good coding. I make it my self to learn recursion and it is working.Please explain.

Comment: Is there any specific part of the code you don't understand?

Comment: "stackoverflaw" is nice.

Comment: @alk "stackoverflaw" :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

- The termination happens too late: you return `a[x]` when `x==n` - that's one element past the end.
- There is a missing return when `a[x] > minima` is false: your function ends without returning `a[x]`.

To fix these two problems, change the check of the termination condition, and add the missing return:

```
if(x >= n-1) return a[n-1];
// You do not need an else after a return
minima = minimum(n,a,x+1);
if (a[x] > minima) return minima;
return a[x];
```

Note that you can save one parameter by starting the search at the end of the array and going backward until you reach index zero.

Comment: so last line returns a[x],when if condition fails right.Do you think this code is correct.Isn't there a possible data set which will give a wrong answer for this method ?

Comment: @KrvPerera No, there is no such data set. You should be able to formally prove it (give it a try, it's fun! All you need is a basic understanding of [mathematical induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction)).

Comment: Okay I am getting it.Is there a some better recursive code to do the same thing.Can it be replaced by a tail recursive function.

Comment: @KrvPerera Yes, there is. To make it tail-recursive, add an extra argument representing the best answer you've found so far, do the comparison first, and then return the result of the recursive call.